# MarGo for Sublime

Tags: go

I tried to install MarGo for GoSublime

```
go get github.com/DisposaBoy/MarGo
```

However it appears that the path is not correct. Has MarGo moved, or it's not needed anymore for GoSublime ?

**Update** MarGo is part of GoSublime apparently.

Comment: The 404 that url gives is a pretty good indicator that it moved...

Comment: But to where? I'm not able to find it

Comment: It's been gone a long time. Maybe it's part of GoSublime?  Why not ask DisposaBoy if GoSublime is missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Command margo](http://godoc.org/github.com/DisposaBoy/GoSublime/src/gosubli.me/margo): `github.com/DisposaBoy/GoSublime/src/gosubli.me/margo`

[GoSublime/src/gosubli.me/margo](https://github.com/DisposaBoy/GoSublime/tree/master/src/gosubli.me/margo): `github.com/DisposaBoy/GoSublime/tree/master/src/gosubli.me/margo`

Comment: Hello Peter, sorry what do you mean by Command margo ?  I tried to access it but it gives me 404

Comment: @Marin: I've added a direct link to the source code.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was wondering if I need MarGo or not , seems that it is part of GoSublime which I have installed already.